# Slow Context menu in windows 11

Tags: video, performance, windows-11, context-menu, file-extension

Context menu in W11 is so sluggish (specially on video files) i uninstalled everything that i suspected to be the cause and used the tool called "This Is Windows 11" to uninstall all the microsoft preinstalled crap and nothing worked..

i went ahead and did a fresh install, installed all the updates, before installing anything else, i used this registry tweak to disable the new context menu and bring back the classic one

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}\InprocServer32]
@=""
```

it worked perfectly, the classic menu is back and it's snappy as ever.. except on video files, it could take seconds to load!! very annoying! (the bigger the file the longer it takes)

i booted the pc on safe mode and the problem was gone, the menu loads instantaneously.. so it has to be something that loads in the normal boot that's causing the problem.. i need some assistance pointing out the cause of that issue and disable it.. thank you for any help

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is almost 100% for sure a shell extension.

It is almost assured that you have installed that only gets loaded when you right click a video file.  Probably a video player or video editor.  It is very unlikely that it is Microsoft but it *could* be.

1. Try the [Shell Extension Viewer](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html).  We will be using it to specifically look for "Context Menu" entries.
2. Look down for the column that says "File extensions" AND has "Context Menu" and find your file type that it is happening for.
3. If you don't get a hit there.. look for the obvious thing you installed among the other extensions you see (also "Context Menu").

Disable, disable, disable.

If you use this tool to disable/enable extensions, there will be no big deal putting it back.

Keep in mind that these extensions might provide some sort of functionality that you want to have.  You cannot have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: Already tried Shell Extension Viewer, nothing i've installed coule be the cause.. it's beside the point though, since the problem is there even on a clean windows install..

Comment: @Kareem .. When you right click a specific file type and only that file type (or similar) there is a lag?  If it isn't the shell running an extension, then what else could it be?  Even a clean windows install has extensions loaded.  This is how the explorer works.  Note that I said that it *could be* Microsoft (but usually isn't)?  Yes, I have been known to disable their extensions too.

Answer (score 0):

Restart explorer, refresh desktop, repeat until it improves.

I was able to reduce the delay up to 90%. This variation is enough to prove that it is not related to installed apps or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I've also enabled the classic menu and turned off 3rd party shell extensions. The context menu of video files was still delayed by seconds (not exaggerating).

There was a menu entry called `Edit with Clipchamp`. I decided to uninstall **Clipchamp** and the menu got relieved. It is still slower on video files than on other files and sometimes it still takes seconds, but it became less frequent and less annoying than before.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).